# can you do paypal integration with asp.net c# even though your website is still offline?

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

We are working on a system with a paypal integrated system. but i'm having doubts, should we Host our site first? or can we do our paypal integration even though it is on a trial mode. or just using the local server.
Please guys help me out. I'm confused. T_T

Answer (score 3):

Use the [sandbox](https://developer.paypal.com/) mode! :)

Alternatively, you can deploy your website to a public server, paying attention to allow access only from developers' machines (ie. restricting allowed IPs, using authentication, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have a live / publicly accessible site prior to integrating paypal.  They don't care that much.

When getting started your paypal account is already in trial mode.  When you are ready to flip the switch to go live the paypal servers you communicate with are different.  You'll make that change (it is a configuration setting right?) and log in to paypal to switch it over.